# How to fix flex-direction: column How to have a flex that the first two elements are row direction the last column

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I’m trying to build a div that does the following:
On the left, there is a date. Next to it is an edit button. Under these two elements, I have some text. I’m not able to get the text under the two elements.

I was using flex to achieve this and I broke each element into a separate div.
The last elements I used flex-direction: column; to make sure it goes under the first two.

However with no success.

```css
/* _________________________
  This is the containers for my_thought page


*/
#blocks {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;


}

#blocks div{

flex: 0 0 100px;
padding: 10px 0;
text-align: center;

}



.one{order: 0;}; 
.two{order: 1;};
.three{
 order: 2;
 flex-direction: column;
   
};
/*________________________     */
```

```html
    <div class="Thoughts" id="blocks">
              <div class="one">
              <h2>Date: 
                  <?php $date = strtotime($row['date_created']);
                       echo date('m/d/y', $date);
                       
                  

                  ?>
            
              </h2>
              </div>  
              <div class="justify-content-center .button .two">  
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit post</button>
              </div>
              
            <div class="three">
             <br>
            <p>
              <?php echo $row['text']; ?>
               
               </p>
            </div>
```

I am attaching a photo showing how my code looks currently.
What am I doing wrong?

You can find a photo of the output the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q90qE6mWHZtrcXnAXJdUuSUqHtHt31ig/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Share code, not just images please

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.
I was able to solve the problem.
I am showing the code I used solve the problem.

```css
#blocks {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  

}

#blocks div{

flex: 1 0 100px;
padding: 1px 0;
text-align: center;

}



.one{
  order: 0;
  margin: 10px;
 }; 
.two{order: 1;
  margin: 10px;

};
```

```html
  <div class="Thoughts">
         <div id="blocks">
            
              <div class="one">
                  
              <h2>Date:
                  <?php $date = strtotime($row['date_created']);
                       echo date('m/d/y', $date);         
                   ?>
            
                </h2>
           
              </div>  
              <div class="justify-content-center .button .two">  
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit post</button>
              </div>
              
           </div>
            <p>
              <?php echo $row['text']; ?>
               
               </p>
            
        
     </div>
```